# How to run a nodejs app over HTTPS?

Tags: https, nginx, vps, node-js

I have a node.js app that I want to deploy on a VPS. So I ran the app on port 8080, then went to `IP_ADDRESS:8080` and the website was there. So the next step was removing that port number because I don't want users to have to type the domain and then the port to access the website. So I found out that the default port is 80 and it's http based. So then I just needed to start the app. For that purpose I used pm2 tool to run 24/7 (previously I had to kill port 80 because it was blocked with command `lsof -t -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen | xargs kill`).

Now the app is running but the problem is that I need the website to be served over https. So I bought certificates (received 5 files: certificate.crt, certificate_chain.crt, certificate.csr, certificate.key, certificate.pfx) and now I have a problem trying to run the website on https. I've heard of Nginx, but do I need it, and do I need to use pm2 with Nginx? Do I need Nginx to be able to redirect traffic from http to https and to verify certificates?

Comment: You don't strictly need Nginx if the only functionality you need is HTTPS support. See this related [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998795/2234742).